# How to use a new column as a flag to show Null row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have table A:

```
id
1
2
3
4
5
```

and table B:

```
id
2
3
4
```

I left join A and B:

```
id id
1  NULL
2  2 
3  3
4  4
5  NULL
```

And how can I get a new column like this:

```
id  id     flag
1   NULL   0
2   2      1
3   3      1
4   4      1
5   NULL   0
```

Generally speaking, I want all rows in A but not in B to be flaged as 0 and want all rows in both tables to be flaged as 1. How can I achieve that? Better not use CTE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a `CASE` expression:

```
CASE WHEN B.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS flag
```

Alternatively, you could use an `IIF` (which is shorthand `CASE` expression):

```
IIF(b.id IS NULL, 0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `exists`:

```
select a.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from b where b.id = a.id
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag
from a;
```

The purpose of using `exists` instead of `left join` is that you are guaranteed to not get duplicate rows -- even if `id`s are duplicated in `b`.  That is a nice guarantee.

From a performance perspective, the two should be similar, but it is possible that the `case` is an iota faster.